# Show that $S=\{p\in P_7 : x^2+4x−1\text{ is a factor of }p(x)\}$ is a subspace of $P_7$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $S=\{p\in P_7 : x^2+4x−1\text{ is a factor of }p(x)\}$ is a subspace of $P_7$.
How do I prove S is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  If $p_1(x)=(x^2+4x-1) q_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)=(x^2+4x-1)q_2(x)$, what can you say about $p_1(x)+p_2(x)$?  What about $cp_1(x)$?